# ReactJS: onClick handler not firing when placed on a child component

Tags: reactjs

I recently started working with `ReactJS`. Specifically, I am utilizing the `react-rails` ruby gem and `react-bootstrap` components.

I have a question regarding placing `onClick` event listeners in child components.

As you can see from the code sample below, I have a parent component that 'calls' a child component in its `render` function. Within that `render` function, I have React `onClick` listener that calls `handleToggle` when it is clicked.

```coffee
###* @jsx React.DOM ###

ToggleIconButton = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    toggleOn: false
  handleToggle: (evt) ->
    this.setState(toggleOn: !this.state.toggleOn)
  render: ->
    `<IconButton onClick={this.handleToggle}>Toggle Button</IconButton>`

IconButton = React.createClass
  render: ->
    # BsButton and BsGlyphicon are React-Bootstrap components
    `<BsButton>
      <BsGlyphicon glyph={this.props.glyph} />
      {" " + this.props.text}
     </BsButton>`
```

---

Unfortunately, this doesn't work the way I thought it would. `ToggleIconButton::handleToggle` never gets called. Instead, the `onClick` listener is placed on `IconButton` and references `ToggleIconButton::handleToggle`.

[image: React Dev Tool Screen]

---

I don't want to add any additional behavior to `IconButton`. The way I see it, no conditional logic should be placed in `IconButton`. All it should do is represent an icon and button and not have to worry about any browser events. That's what `ToggleIconButton` is for.

While I know I could wrap a `React Div` around `IconButton` and write an `onClick` listener there (I've tried this and it works), it seems like that's a bit janky.

Does anybody know a good way of doing this? Thanks guys!

Comment: duplicate of [can we attach click handlers to custom child components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469968/can-we-attach-click-handlers-to-custom-child-components)

Comment: there is a subtle difference for `<ActualJSXChildComponents />` that makes [the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872632/react-js-composing-components-to-create-tabs) worth reading

Answer (score 81, accepted):

So, the proper way to handle eventing in this case would be to pass the event handler down to the child component. There are a few ways to accomplish what you want, and I might implement this behavior differently (not sure what the use case is), but I wired up an example in JSX for you that demonstrates the typical event handling between Parent and Child Components. You can find it here...

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TpnG/171/)

Just think of it like this:

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <ChildComponent onSomeEvent={this.handleThatEvent} />;
        )
    },
    handleThatEvent: function(e){
         //update state, etc.
    }
});

var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
           <input type="button" onClick={this.props.onSomeEvent} value="Click Me!" />
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks cap. As you can see from the original post, I do indeed have ReactJS dev tools installed :). While I understand that within my child component I can add an `onClick` listener that will call a function from the child's `props`, it seems like I shouldn't have to do this... what if the child component shouldn't necessarily have an onClick listener in other contexts? What if I want to use this component within a different parent component but not have an onClick listener? Doesn't this harm the reusability of a component?

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are correct sir, I glossed right over that :) So, what you could do, is wrap that component in a div, and register the onClick for that div to get the functionality you want without polluting the ChildComponent with that behavior. Something like <div onClick={this.handleToggle}> <ChildComponent /> </div>

Comment: Also, without clearly passing that event to the ChildComponent, you can't exactly call onClick on it, since the Component itself isn't really an HTML element, so onClick isn't defined for it.

Comment: Thanks! Save my day! :D Needless to say, one must take care of binding the parent component for correct scope & behaviour.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! It is really helpful :)

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to make a child component if before you call the node you create a var to reference the render's this i.e.

```
var self = this;
```

So for example (this is contrived and the var self isn't needed in this case, but in the case of nested return statements it would be required).

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        return (
            <input type="button" onClick={self.handleThatEvent} value="Click Me!" />;
        )
    },
    handleThatEvent: function(e){
         //update state, etc.
    }
});
```

Better yet, you could bind this to the function.

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            this.state.array.map(function(){
              return (<input type="button" onClick={this.handleThatEvent} value="Click Me!" />);
            }.bind(this));
        )
    },
    handleThatEvent: function(e){
         //update state, etc.
    }
});
```

Or to follow captray's suggestion in the comments

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            this.state.array.map(function(){
              return (<input type="button" onClick={this.handleThatEvent} value="Click Me!" />);
            }, this);
        )
    },
    handleThatEvent: function(e){
         //update state, etc.
    }
});
```

Comment: What scope does the handleThatEvent have?  Will it have the childs props or the parents props?

Comment: Try it and see. But it would be the parents, as per the binding.

Comment: great, thanks this solution works when you have multiple returns(3 in my case)

Comment: @RaySuelzer handleThatEvent has the scope of the function. So in the first example since self is a variable set outside of the function, handleThatEvent is attached to self and the self is the parent's this (since self is set to the this of the parent and not set to a different value in the child). In the second example handleThatEvent has the parent's this because of the .bind(this) call. Both functions have their own scope though.

Comment: Just a heads up, for those looking to use bind in this scenario... Many of the functional calls like map and filter accept a second parameter, which does the same thing as bind, it sets the execution context to what is passed in, so you can just call .map(function(item) { //do stuff }, this);

Comment: This is great! I am new to React and was just refactoring my app to be simpler and more elegant ... spent a day trying to figure out why some nested child^parent calls were broken. This (no pun intended) fixed everything!

Comment: [eslint] JSX props should not use arrow functions (react/jsx-no-bind)