# [React/JSX]: Remove CSS classes on sibling components, when the current component is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm building a navigation bar with React. The Navigation bar has various navigation items. When one of the navigation items is clicked, the class 'active' has to be added to the clicked item (this part is easily achievable with a new state tracking if it's active).

However when the 'active' class is added to one of the navigation items, the active class has to be removed from any other navigation items currently having it. This is straightforward with jQuery, but I'm guessing thats not the React best practice. What's the ideal way to remove the 'active' class from the sibling navigation items?

Comment: I think that you should resolve this on container level (Navigation bar) rather than in navigation item. Navigation Bar should know about its children. Items(children of navigation bar) don't need to know about each  other.

Comment: Talk is cheap. I have shown the code below ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the best approach would be handle this in the container component. Menu items don't need to know about each other, but container can. So container can give to children onClick callbacks. And later in callbacks container can set its state by `setState`. In `render` function you just pass `active` property to your MenuItem.

```
// ES6, React 0.14
var MenuItem = ({onClick, text, active}) => (
    <button onClick={onClick} style={active? {color: 'red'} : null}>{text}</button>
);

// example of use: <MenuBar buttons={['cat', 'dog', 'penguin']}/>
class MenuBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {activeIndex: 0};
    }
    handleItemClick(index) {
        this.setState({activeIndex: index});
    }
    render() {
        var activeIndex = this.state.activeIndex;
        return <div>
            {
                this.props.buttons.map(
                    (btn, i) => (
                        <MenuItem
                            active={activeIndex === i}
                            key={i}
                            onClick={this.handleItemClick.bind(this, i)}
                            text={btn} />
                    )
                )
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the general approach is correct (hence the accepted answer), there is an error in this code, inside the MenuBar::render, you have added an onClick which is supposed to call handleItemClick. But this will not trigger. See this discussion for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103072/reactjs-onclick-handler-not-firing-when-placed-on-a-child-component

Comment: It should work because I checked this. Check for yourself:  https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/20164/  . I used ES6 fat arrow(`=>`) syntax which preserves automatically `this` variable.

Comment: off course to make this example work you don't have to use fat arrow syntax, it's just syntax sugar that comes with ES6. This example could be written as well in ES5. General approach stays the same).

Answer (score 2):

I've started learning React recently so I'm not an expert. But I just started building some tabs and you can see my example [here](http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/qOMyEp?editors=001).

What I did was make a conditional isActive state that changed on a click event. Then the class was changed like so:

```
className={this.props.isActive ? "active" : null}
```