# Separating presentational and logic components react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, redux

I'm trying to clean up my components so that my container handles logic and my components are presentational only. I'm using Redux to connect my store to container/components.

I'm trying this simple code, and I'm not sure why it is not working and what I'm missing.

Previously I had, and it worked:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
       var style = this.props.hover;
       var actions = this.props.actions;
       return (
           <div>
              <Bullet style={style} actions = {actions}/>
           </div>
       );
    }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
      hover: state.hover
   }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
     actions: Redux.bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

var MainConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)    (Main);


module.exports = MainConnected;
```

And here was my `Bullet` component:

```
var Bullet = React.createClass({
   over: function(){
      this.props.actions.ON();
   },
   out: function(){
      this.props.actions.OFF();
   },
   render: function(){
      var style = this.props.style;
      return(
         <div id="bullet" style = {style} onMouseOver = {this.over} onMouseOut = {this.out}></div>
      );
   }
   });
```

Now, I tried this:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    over: function(){
        console.log('hey');
    },
    out: function(){
        this.props.dispatch(actions.OFF()); 
    },
    render: function(){
        var style = this.props.hover;
        return (
            <div>
                <Bullet id="Git" style={style} onMouseOver = {this.over} onMouseOut = {this.out}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

//and Bullet component

var Bullet = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var style = this.props.style;
        return(
            <div id="bullet" style = {style} ></div>
        );
    }
});
```

I removed the `over` and `out` logic from the `Button` but they're not working when called from the Main container. I think I'm misunderstanding how to use `this` too because the `console.log()` is not being called.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction as to how to separate this logic and maybe helping understand how `this` is used in React. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

oh, got it.
This helped: [ReactJS: onClick handler not firing when placed on a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103072/reactjs-onclick-handler-not-firing-when-placed-on-a-child-component?rq=1)

I had to pass my functions from Parent to Child. So the code looks like this:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    over: function(){
        this.props.dispatch(actions.ON());  
    },
    out: function(){
        this.props.dispatch(actions.OFF()); 
    },
    render: function(){
    var style = this.props.hover;
        return (
            <div>
                <Bullet id="Git" style={style} over = {this.over} out = {this.out}/>
            </div>
        );
   }
});

var Bullet = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var style = this.props.style;
        var over = this.props.over;
        var out = this.props.out;
        return(
            <div id="bullet" style = {style} onMouseOver = {over} onMouseOut = {out}></div>
        );
    }
});
```