# Is it possible to separate presentation and logic for component in Redux/React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

As showed in official docs of redux -> https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react, the logic and presetation must been tied together.

The question is - is it real, that we cannot separate them to make our code more clear?

For example some component from official redux.js.org docs. So, the logic and pres are together in it and it's not looking so good and clear:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'
 
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input
 
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ''
        }}
      >
        <input
          ref={node => {
            input = node
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)
 
export default AddTodo
```

P.S.
Also I saw this question: [Separating presentational and logic components react/redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091875/separating-presentational-and-logic-components-react-redux) , this is not the same.

> UPD:
>   I had separate the logic into onSubmit module and component presentation. But > for now I get an error - `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` :

/* PRESENTATION */

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AddTodo from '../../Actions/AddTodo'
import addTodo from '../../Modules/handleClick'

class AddTodos extends React.Component{    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(addTodo()); // for test. Get "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function"
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" />
                <button type="submit">Add todos</button>
            </form>
        );  
    }
}

export default AddTodos;
```

/* ONSUBMIT MODULE */

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AddTodo from '../Actions/AddTodo'

let addTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        let form = document.querySelector('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', handleClick);

        function handleClick(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let input = document.querySelector('input');    
            dispatch(AddTodo(input.value));

            input.value = '';
        }
    }
}

addTodo = connect()(addTodo);

export default addTodo;
```

Comment: You can move the `onSubmit` handler into a separate class method,

Comment: I had separate this case into onSubmit module and just presentation. But now I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` when invoke the `onSubmit `module inside `component`. UPD the question

Comment: You are using an action creator like a function. addTodo is not a function, it is an action creator and must be used with dispatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the same documentation you gave:

> Sometimes it's hard to tell if some component should be a
>   presentational component or a container. For example, sometimes form
>   and function are really coupled together, such as in the case of this
>   tiny component:
>
> ```
> AddTodo is an input field with an “Add” button
> ```
>
> **Technically we could split it into two components but it might be too
>   early at this stage**. It's fine to mix presentation and logic in a
>   component that is very small. **As it grows, it will be more obvious how
>   to split it, so we'll leave it mixed.**

So yes you are right, it is better to separate our presentational and container components and it is explained very well in the documentation as you stated. The example you gave is just an exception.

Here how you can separate the components:

**AddTodo**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../actions";
import AddTodoForm from "./AddTodoForm";

const AddTodo = ( props ) => {
    const handleAddTodo = todo => props.dispatch( addTodo( todo ) );

    return (
        <AddTodoForm addTodo={handleAddTodo} />
    );
};

export default connect()( AddTodo );
```

**AddTodoForm**

```
import React from "react";

const AddTodoForm = ( props ) => {
    let input;

    const handleClick = () => {
        props.addTodo( input.value );
        input.value = "";
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <input
                ref={( node ) => {
                    input = node;
                }}
            />
            <button
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
    Add Todo
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddTodoForm;
```

I strongly advise you to watch Redux videos on Egghead from Dan Abramov (creator of Redux). You will understand the logic of Redux from scratch after watching those videos. There are two parts, watch both parts. While I studying Redux I watched those and write all the codes while watching. After that I created a repo: https://github.com/devserkan/react-with-idiomatic-redux

You can clone this repo and play as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot figure out how to separate the presentation and logic in this current case. Maybe you know and can make it? I had update the question and implement my realization of it, but it's not work...

Comment: For this current case there will be a component name AddTodoForm and includes a simple form. It will have a handleSubmit function and it will pass the input value to the real function that will do the dispatch. That function will be in our container component and it will pass that function to our AddTodoForm. So, for a simple form things get crazy. This is why documentation says it is too early for this stage. Let me do this if I have time.

Comment: Consider using the controller/presentational component pattern https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @AnthonyManning-Franklin. I revisited my code and wrote the components as functions.