# Separating the logic and the render() function from a component

Tags: javascript, react-native, code-organization

I would like to be able to have a component whose rendering function is in another file in order to have a separation between the logic of my component and the rendering.

Naively, I tried to do just one file containing my component and which rendered a functional component of the same name to which I passed the necessary props so that everything was displayed correctly.

Something like that :

```js
// MyComponent.render.jsx
export default MyComponentRender = (props) => {
    return {
        <View>
            // render all components of my view
        </View>
    }
}


// MyComponent.js
class MyComponent extends Component {
    // some logic

    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponentRender
                aLotOfProps=....
            />
        )
    }
}
```

But I soon found myself having to send, sometimes, a fairly large amount of props and +, I have for example textInputs that need to be focus() or blur() in reaction to some logic in my view but as a result, I couldn't control that just by sending props. It quickly became a mess!

I was wondering if there was a simple way to separate the logic of a component and its rendering function? Maybe there is a way to pass the context of my component to my rendering function/component so that it has direct access to all states and can also store references, etc.?

Thanks you,

Viktor

Comment: If you prefer this way of strict separation of concerns (which I can fully understand), why not work with Angular instead of React? Angular has some fantastic mobile support with frameworks like Ionic.

Comment: Can you show us your files ? 
In general you should try to keep the maximum of logic out of components and when the become too big try to split them in smaller ones if possible

Comment: Please go through the below links
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588173/is-it-possible-to-separate-presentation-and-logic-for-component-in-redux-react

Comment: It's hard to give a proper answer without looking at what you have... may be you can share much of your code in the question and also create something in http://www.codesandbox.io

Comment: Without code demonstrating the issues you're trying to work around, it's hard to provide meaningful advice. At a high level though, you can always separate logic from components by creating utility functions that exist outside of your component. These could be additional hooks (perhaps for the `blur` and `focus` case you allude to), or just plain old functions for common processing. In terms of passing large numbers of props, look into contexts. They may help you separate data in your application more logically, and avoid prop drilling (if that is why you are passing so many props).